# multi-select tagged value type in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to add a Tagged Value in Enterprise Architect which allows the selection of one or more values, a multi-select tagged value type in effect.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Xstian's answer is partially correct if you're working with profiles. However, it only provides you with a select-from-a-list tag type (and you should not import profiles directly into a project, you should create MDG Technologies instead).

EA also allows you to create what are known as structured tagged values. These come in different flavours, and allow you to select a value from an enum list, a file name from a browser dialog, a date from a calendar, and many others -- including classes in the same model.

These tagged value types are configured in Settings - UML Types - Tagged Value Types. The syntax is described in the help file under Extending UML Models - MDG Technology SDK - Tagged Value Types - Predefined Types (but note that you do not need to create an MDG Technology or even a profile for these tag types to work).

Answer (score 0):

You can add to any model element more than one tagged value of the same name - each of them can have different value. Together they logically constitute "set of values" (i.e. multi-valued tag).

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is.

I solved in this way.

You should create a your Stereotype
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/extending_uml_models/addingelementsandmetaclass.html

(e.g. see image)

[image]

You should export this profile in XML and import it into EnterpriseArchitect
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/extending_uml_models/importingprofiles.html

Add this stereotype to your class,connector, etc

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question

Comment: I think the question was to allow for multiple select. This will only allow you to select a single value from the enum.